# Ошибка Pyinstaller при компиляции exe файла

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

Делаю exe файл с помощью pyinstaller, появляется ошибка:

```
Syntax error in C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Scripts\SGRG.py
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Scripts\SGRG.py", line 84
     except FileNotFoundError:
 IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Это не ошибка компиляции, это проблема с отступами в файле SGRG.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы запускали код перед сборкой(намёк)? Судя по всему - нет. У вас некорректная табуляция/отступы в `SGRG.py`. Изучите синтаксис языка, чтобы понять как устроены отступы в Python, как и где их делать.
Итого:
Здесь нет ошибки со стороны pyinstaller, ошибка со стороны кода, который сначала надо просто запустить и убедиться, что он корректно работает

Comment: Спасибо большое!